# VLookup to Replace Table Content from Data Source

Tags: excel, vba

I'm programming a Macro to Refresh Data from a DataSource and the copy a copy of the comments added to the file into the table the Data is located in.

I've tried changing the columns I'm copying from and replicating this without disabling background refresh( w/o Refresh this worked but the Refresh will finish after the Macro Complete wiping my Vlookup)

```
Sub RefreshAndDelete3()
' This Macro Will Copy over the First Five Columns
' Then Delete the Original Data
' Refresh the Data & Vlookup the Comments back
'

    'This Block Sets Variables for Sheets and Makes RawData Sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ReadyB As Worksheet: Set ReadyB = wb.Sheets("Ready Board")
    ReadyB.Visible = True
    Dim RawD As Worksheet
    Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Raw Data"
    Set RawD = wb.Sheets("Raw Data")

    'This Block Copies and Pastes A:F Data to RawData
    Dim AF As Range
    Set AF = ReadyB.Columns("A:F")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    AF.Copy
    RawD.Paste
    Set AF = ReadyB.Columns("M")
    AF.Copy
    RawD.Paste Destination:=RawD.Range("G1")
    RawD.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

    'This Refreshes the Data
    Dim Connection As Variant
    For Each Connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        Connection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    Next Connection
    wb.RefreshAll

    'ThisExecutes a VLookup
    Dim ReadyLastRow As Long, DataLastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    DataLastRow = RawD.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReadyLastRow = ReadyB.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set DataRange = RawD.Range("A2:G" & DataLastRow)
    For x = 2 To ReadyLastRow
        On Error Resume Next
        ReadyB.Range("F" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
            ReadyB.Range("M" & x).Value, DataRange, 6, False)
    Next x

    'This Deletes the Raw Data Sheet & Hides the Board Then Sets Home
    ReadyB.Visible = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    RawD.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("Home").Select

End Sub
```

I expect that as soon as the Connection is Refreshed the VLookUp will copy the Comment Column in the "Raw Data" sheet(Column F on both Sheets) back into the comment Column in the "Ready board" Sheet and then delete the Raw Data sheet.

The VLookUp should be comparing the Unique IDs that get copied over from the 
Ready Board and then adding the Comments (if any) back into the Ready Board Table AFTER the Data Connection is Refreshed.

[image: SampleData]
Raw Data
[image: RawData]

Comment: Show us how your data is arranged. If its confidential, post a sample.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I included a sample of how my Data is arranged. Should be easier to examine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, My Issue seems to have been caused by my Misunderstanding of the VLOOKUP function. I had the Unique IDs in the Raw Data sheet in the Last Column. This meant that the VLOOKUP could not find the ID properly. Upon switching it to the First Column the VLOOKUP returned the correct data in the Comment Column of my Table.

As Shown Below:
[image: New Layout]
When I did this the VLOOKUP performed as expected.
This is the only part of the Macro I changed.

```
    'This Block Copies and Pastes A:F Data to RawData
    Dim AF As Range
    Set AF = ReadyB.Columns("M")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    AF.Copy
    RawD.Paste
    Set AF = ReadyB.Columns("A:F")
    AF.Copy
    RawD.Paste Destination:=RawD.Range("B1")
    RawD.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
```